# europecv stack exceeding

Tags: europecv, stack, hungarian

I'm writing a CV with the `europecv` package, which I'd like to have in hungarian. But with the `hungarian` option in the `\documentclass` command the hyphenation is wrong. Loading the corresponding `babel` package (`\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`) gives the error:

```
 TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\magyar@@orig@refstepcounter ...refstepcounter {#1
                                                  }\begingroup \c@page \@m \...
l.20    \begin{europecv}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal example is needed; but in my experience, the `magyar.ldf` file has several incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal example for reproducing the error is:

```
\documentclass[hungarian]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
x
\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

`magyar.ldf` redefines `\refstepcounter` in a way which causes an infinite recursion here. Since you are in the lucky situation that you should not really need that macro, specifically its hungarian version, you can backup and restore it. Then the error goes away.

```
\let\myrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\let\refstepcounter\myrefstepcounter
```